# Uniqueness of Differential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Hey guys hope you're all doing well. I'm preparing for an upcoming midterm and I've got this question I've been stuck on for a while:

"Suppose $y = φ_1(t)$ and $y = φ_2(t)$ are solutions to the initial
value problem $y'= t + y^2$,  $y(0) = 0$
on the interval $t \in [0, 1]$. Show that $φ_1(t) = φ_2(t)$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$.

Hint: For your estimates you may assume that a continuous function on a
closed and bounded interval attains its minimum and maximum value and thus
it is bounded."

I've been at it for a while now and all I've managed to definitely figure out is that $y' \geq 0$ because on the interval [0, 1], $t + y^2$ is always going to be positive and that $φ_1(0) = φ_2(0) = y(0) = 0$. That's all I've managed to figure out. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sketch:** Observe
\begin{align}
\varphi_1(t)-\varphi_2(t) =&\   \int^t_0 \varphi'_1(s)-\varphi_2'(s)\ ds  = \int^t_0 \varphi_1^2(s)-\varphi_2^2(s)\ ds\\
=&\ \int^t_0 (\varphi_1(s)-\varphi_2(s))(\varphi_1(s)+\varphi_2(s))\ ds.
\end{align}
Then it follows
\begin{align}
|\varphi_1(t)-\varphi_2(t)| \leq&\  \int^t_0 |\varphi_1(s)-\varphi_2(s)|\{|\varphi_1(s)|+|\varphi_2(s)|\}\ ds\\
\leq&\ 2M\int^t_0 |\varphi_1(s)-\varphi_2(s)|\ ds. 
\end{align}
If we define
\begin{align}
F(t) := \int^t_0 |\varphi_1(s)-\varphi_2(s)|\ ds
\end{align}
then it follows $F'(t) = |\varphi_1(t)-\varphi_2(t)|$. Hence we have $F'(t) \leq 2MF(t)$.

Finally, note that
\begin{align}
F'(t)-2M F(t) \leq 0  \ \ \implies \ \ (e^{-2Mt}F(t))' \leq 0 
\end{align}
which means 
\begin{align}
e^{-2Mt}F(t) - F(0) \leq 0 \ \ \implies \ \ F(t) \leq F(0)e^{2Mt}. 
\end{align}
Hence we have the desired result.

Comment: One could add that this type of argument starting from the second formula has the umbrella name "Grönwall lemma".